# Get user relation users in parse query ionic4

Tags: parse-platform, ionic4, parse-server, parse-dashboard

I have the following parse query:

```
  loadAllFriends(params: any = {}): Promise<User[]> {
    const page = params.page || 0;
    const limit = params.limit || 20;
    const query = new Parse.Query(User);
    const user = Parse.User.current();
    const relation = user.relation('likes');
    query.equalTo('likes', user);

    query.descending('updatedAt');
    query.skip(page * limit);
    query.limit(limit);
    return query.find();
  }
```

...and i load the data in page.ts like:

```
 const users = await this.userService.loadAllFriends(this.params);
  console.log(users);
  for (let user of users) {
    this.users.push(user);
  }
```

... So this code it queries **const user = Parse.User.current();** in **likes** relation column, checks if user is there and returns the results.

I need exact the opposite, with the anterior query i get the friends, but i need to get the followers. The followers are stored in user -> likes relation column:

[image]
[image]

> How can i query user like:

```
 const user = Parse.User.current();
 query.equalTo('objectId', user.id);
```

> ... and here get the likes relation data from this user?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can do what you're trying to with a relation.  I think that you'll need to model these relationships with a table:

`{ fromUser, toUser, status }`